# Why does my dog poop in the house when he's alone?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

My dog is a three year old Shiba Inu/Yorkie mix. No matter how frequent his potty breaks are, he only poops when nobody is home (never longer than 2 hours).

He was alone for an hour and 30 minutes today and he pooped twice, but absolutely will not go when I take him outside. I've had him for a week and I suspect he was abused in the past. Of all the times I've taken him outside in the last week, he has pooped outside 4 times. Every time I come home there is poop on the floor.

I know he knows what he did was naughty too because he looks nervous when I come home and there's poop on the floor (I've never laid a hand on him). I'm starting him on a regular feeding and toileting routine. I will also be crating him for the short time that he will be alone. Is there anything else I can do? Every time he went outside I would give him a lot of praise and playtime. I give him treats every time he pees and poos outside. He hasn't shown any symptoms of separation anxiety, he just poops when nobody is home.

Comment: How old is he and where did you get him from? Knowledge of past is helpful

Answer (score 3):

> I know he knows what he did was naughty too because he looks nervous when I come home and there's poop on the floor (I've never laid a hand on him).

Good you never did, keep that up :).
But ARE you possibly tense and annoyed when you come home, right? Your dog does NOT connect your annoyance with him pooping earlier! All he knows is that you come home, and you are annoyed! So, there are two separate issues:
The potty-training: keep up the potty-training for outside. If he poops outside, you are absolutely delighted, he did the greatest thing ever.  Hopefully, he will come around.

About his nervousness:
When you come home, you are delighted, too! You love coming home to your doggie! Seeing your doggie again is the greatest thing ever! You absolutely ignore the fact that he has pooped on the floor. If you scold him when he pooped while you where gone, all he knows is: You come home, you are annoyed! He has NO idea why!   After having been delighted to see your dog again, you clean up. That's a separate thing from your dog, though. He did something wrong, yes, but it is too late to correct him!

I hope this helps a bit :). Always remind yourself: anything that's more than a a few seconds ago? If you reward or discipline it, your dog won't make the connection. All consequences have to be immediate! Good luck :).